# how can retrive specific data for each user by using eloquent in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, database, eloquent, laravel-8

I have two tables in Database, user table and meeting table.
when a user login successfully I want that the information in the meeting table shown to them.
but not all of them just the one which he created them or invited to.

this ids my route:

```
   Route::get('/dashboard/per_user{id}',[meetingController::class, 'meet_for_user'])- 
    >name('meet_for_user');
```

this is my controller:

```
  public function meet_for_user()
{
    $meetings=meeting::with('users')->get();

    return view('dashboard', compact('meetings'));
}
```

this is user model:

```
  public function meeting()
{
    return $this->hasMany(meeting::class,'idCreateMeeting','id');
}
```

this is meeting model:

```
     public function users()
      {
     return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'idCreateMeeting','id');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change how your route is defined to expect a `User` `id`, you can use [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding) to inject the `User` into your controller method and get their meetings from there.

```
Route::get('/dashboard/per_user/{user}',[meetingController::class, 'meet_for_user'])
    ->name('meet_for_user');
```

```
public function meet_for_user(User $user)
{
    $meetings = $user->meetings;
    return view('dashboard', compact('meetings'));
}
```